# Setting state with methods passed into dumb components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

Within my smart component, I have methods that I want to use to set state of my smart component. When a user interacts with the dumb component, the methods passed down from the smart component will be triggered and that to change the state of my smart component

In my code below, I want my `setHighlight` to change my `state.highlight` to a string `onClick`. `clearHighlight` has the same functionality except it sets `this.state.highlight = null`. Once this state has been set, `this.state.highlight` is passed to my `PrettyPrintPageSource` in order to perform the logic in `highlightTag`.

My code is currently showing these errors:

```
warning.js:44Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the HomePage component.warning @ warning.js:44

warning.js:44Warning: Failed prop type: Required prop `setHighlightTag` was not specified in `TagSummary`.
    in TagSummary (created by HomePage)
    in HomePage (created by Connect(HomePage))
    in Connect(HomePage) (created by RouterContext)
    in div (created by App)
    in MuiThemeProvider (created by App)
    in App (created by RouterContext)
    in RouterContext (created by Router)
    in Router
    in Providerwarning @ warning.js:44
warning.js:44Warning: Failed prop type: Required prop `clearHighlight` was not specified in `TagSummary`.
    in TagSummary (created by HomePage)
    in HomePage (created by Connect(HomePage))
    in Connect(HomePage) (created by RouterContext)
    in div (created by App)
    in MuiThemeProvider (created by App)
    in App (created by RouterContext)
    in RouterContext (created by Router)
    in Router
    in Provider
```

Here is my code:

```
class HomePage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            highlight: null
        };
        this.getPageSource = this.getPageSource.bind(this);
        this.updateURLstate = this.updateURLstate.bind(this);
        this.highlightTag = this.highlightTag.bind(this);
        this.clearHighlight = this.clearHighlight(this);
        this.setHighlightTag = this.setHighlightTag(this);
    }

    getPageSource(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.actions.getPageSource(this.state.url);
    }

    updateURLstate(event) {
        const url = event.target.value;
        this.setState({
            url
        });
    }

    setHighlightTag(tag) {
        this.setState({
            highlight: tag
        });
    }

    highlightTag(pageSource, tag) {
        if (tag) {
            let re = new RegExp(tag, "g");
            pageSource.replace(re, "<span class='red'>"+ tag +"</span>")
        }
    }

    clearHighlight() {
        this.setState({
            highlight: null
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <UrlForm
                    onSearch={ this.getPageSource }
                    onChange={ this.updateURLstate }
                />

                <PrettyPrintPageSource
                    badUrl={ this.props.payload.error }
                    prettyPrintPageSource={ this.props.payload.prettySource }
                    highlighter={ this.highlightTag }
                    tag={ this.state.highlight }
                />
                <TagSummary
                    tags={ this.props.payload.tagData }
                    setHighlightTag={ this.setHighlightTag }
                    clearHighlight={ this.clearHighlight }
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

TagSummary dumb Component:

```
const TagSummary = ({ tags, setHighlightTag, clearHighlight }) => {
    if (!tags) {
        return <div />;
    }
    return (
        <div>
            {Object.keys(tags).map((tag) => {
                return (
                    <div key={ tag }>
                        <button type="button" onClick={ setHighlightTag.bind(this, tag) }>
                            <pre>&lt;{ tag }&gt;</pre>
                        </button>
                        <p>{ tags[tag] }</p>
                    </div>

                );
            })}
            <button onClick={ clearHighlight }>Clear</button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

PrettyPrintPageSource dumb Component:

```
const PrettyPrintPageSource = ({ prettyPrintPageSource, badUrl, highlighter, tag }) => {
    if (badUrl) {
        return (
            <div>
                Bad URL!
            </div>
        );
    } else {

        let processedPageSource = highlighter.bind(this, prettyPrintPageSource, tag);

        return (
            <pre>
                { processedPageSource }
            </pre>
        );
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot bind `clearHighlight` and `setHighlightTag` methods. Change those lines :

```
  constructor(){
   ....
   this.clearHighlight = this.clearHighlight.bind(this);
   this.setHighlightTag = this.setHighlightTag.bind(this);
   }
```